# Coldfusion - both e-mail cfdocument and print to screen using javascript - don't work together

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfdocument

I am working on a coldfusion website and trying to fix a bug. I've tried many things up until now, so here goes with StackOverflow.

The website in question needs the ability to both e-mail a pdf, and another function to print the pdf to the user for preview in the browser (in another window). I find that no matter what I do, these functions do not work concurrently.

Here is the code to do the e-mailing (coldfusion and JavaScript):

[E-mail function and variables - wouldn't paste correctly in code format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ro4.png)

The document is built using the following cfm file:

[cfdocument file header - wouldn't paste correctly either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tacpy.png)

The code calls the same function (orderApprovalPdf.cfm) for both the print and e-mail abilities. Here is the javascript to call the printing:

```
form = document[this._PARENT.NAME+"MANAGEFORM"];
sel = ColdFusion.getElementValue(this._PARENT.NAME+"FORMSELECT");

switch(sel){

     case 'APPROVAL' :
         window.open('Pdf/orderApprovalPdf.cfm?PRODUCTORDERID=' + form.productOrderID.value);   
     break;
      case 'SHIPDATECONFIRMATION' :
        window.open('Pdf/vikingEstShipDatePdf.cfm?PRODUCTORDERID=' + form.productOrderID.value);    
     break;
     case 'BOL' :
        window.open('Pdf/billOfLadingPdf.cfm?PRODUCTORDERID=' + form.productOrderID.value); 
     break;
      case 'INVOICE' :
        window.open('Pdf/invoicePdf.cfm?INVOICEID=' + form.invoiceID.value);    
     break;
      case 'INVOICECANADA' :
        window.open('Pdf/invoicePdfCanada.cfm?INVOICEID=' + form.invoiceID.value);  
     break;

}
```

I tried all of the following:

A second .cfm file for the print functionality called from `printForm` – different cfm name, different cfm file directory, different path for the temporary file, and different temporary file name – e-mail would break unless the following in bold matched the original pdf function name despite being in the `printForm` function and not the `emailForm` function and appearing in no other places

```
 case 'APPROVAL' :
 window.open('Pdf/orderApprovalPdf.cfm?PRODUCTORDERID=' + form.productOrderID.value);
```

Alternatives to `cfdocument` property filename: saveasname, name (called from `manageOrder.cfc` as a variable such as #myPdf# when that was the name variable of the `cfdocument` – error on this saying myPdf variable did not exist no matter how I called it)

```
   <cfdocument name=”myPdf” >
   <cfmailparam file = “#GetTempDirectory()#Approval_#getApprovalInfoProcResult.ORDERNUMBER#.pdf" type=”application/pdf” content=”#myPdf” />
   <cfcontent variable="#myPdf#" type="application/pdf" reset="Yes">
```

Tried adding `cfcontent` and `cfheader` tags in order to do the file saving (also to circumvent filename as an attribute) – did not make a difference, still couldn’t find the file when e-mail time came:

```
 <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#GetTempDirectory()#Approval_#getApprovalInfoProcResult.ORDERNUMBER#.pdf" />
```

Moved the e-mail functionality from `manageOrder.cfc` to the `orderApprovalPdf(cfm)` file after the close of the `<cfdocument>` tag – but the program never hits this code

Any ideas? Maybe an alternative to `cfdocument`? I tried two separate cfm files and it looks like the `window.open` function does not allow this workaround.